# How to prove exactly one conclusion holds

Tags: proof-writing

Let's say we're given two conclusions A and B and we want to show that only one can be true at once. Can I prove this by assuming A and showing that B cannot be true and vice versa?

Comment: Yes, that method of proof would work.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Comment: @mathnerd Note that the title says "exactly one", but the questions says "only one". These are not the same, and what you said is only good for the "only one" case.

Comment: I didn't even realize I mistyped that. What is the difference, and how would one go about proving the "exactly one" case?

Comment: To prove the **exactly one** case, you need to prove that $$A \implies \neg B ~~~\text{and}~~~ \neg A \implies B.$$  To prove the **no more than one** case, it is sufficient to prove (for example) merely that $$A \implies \neg B.$$  Alternatively, in this second interpretation you could prove that it is **not the case** that $$A ~\text{and}~ B.$$